# Azure Function Returning 503 After 30 Seconds

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, http-status-code-503

I have an Azure Function App running Python `3.9.x` on a consumption tier with a simple function that always returns a 503 after 30 seconds stating:

> Our services aren't available right now.  We're working to restore all services as soon as possible. Please check back soon.

The strange thing is that it does not throw any errors in Application Insights or anything that can be found by `Diagnose and solve problems > Function App Down or Reporting Errors`.  In fact, the function continues to run and completes successfully.  See the `200` responses below:

[image]

I have done all the things that I have read recommended, but I just could not make sense of it.  I've tried:

- Digging through logs for errors
- Adding additional try / catch handling and error logging
- Upgrading to a Standard and Premium App Service Plan
- Adding an explicit timeout of 5 minutes in `host.json`
- Fully destroying and redeploying all resources in different regions, with different configs, and using different SKUs.
- Downgrading the Python version from `3.9` to `3.8`
- Restarting the Function App
- Ensuring all versions of all packages used are pinned and work locally.
- Testing to see if it was an issue with core tools using M1 architecture.

I kept peeling things back to see how simple of a function would fail to help with reproducibility.  Here is a minimal example of an HTTP triggered function that will fail in this way.

****init**.py**

```
import logging
import json

from time import sleep

import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    try:
        sleep(60)
        result = "This worked!"  

    except Exception as e:
        return func.HttpResponse(str(e), status_code=500)

    return func.HttpResponse(
        str(result),
        status_code=200
    )
```

**function.json**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get"
      ],
      "route": "buggy"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```

**host.json**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  }
}
```

**requirements.txt**

```
# DO NOT include azure-functions-worker in this file
# The Python Worker is managed by Azure Functions platform
# Manually managing azure-functions-worker may cause unexpected issues

azure-functions
```

This returns:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'><html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'><head><meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='content-type'/><style type='text/css'>body {font-family:Arial; margin-left:40px; }img  { border:0 none; }#content { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto }#message h2 { font-size: 20px; font-weight: normal; color: #000000; margin: 34px 0px 0px 0px }#message p  { font-size: 13px; color: #000000; margin: 7px 0px 0px0px}#errorref { font-size: 11px; color: #737373; margin-top: 41px }</style><title>Service unavailable</title></head><body><div id='content'><div id='message'><h2>Our services aren't available right now</h2><p>We're working to restore all services as soon as possible. Please check back soon.</p></div><div id='errorref'><span>08yTaYgAAAABTVg4FtYrARaB1kxMaYPzBQVRMMzMxMDAwMTEwMDQ5ADdkYjBhYzFjLWI3NmQtNGJhNC1hMTc1LTU1ODE1NTExMTNkNQ==</span></div></div></body></html>
```

[image]

It is breaking my brain that just sleeping the code for 30 seconds will cause this problem in an Azure function.  I thought maybe it was because `sleep()` was somehow killing the thread or the process causing the host to shut down, but I was able to reproduce the same errors in a while loop that was running a process that took more than 30 seconds without explicitly pausing execution.

There are a lot of people with this issue and no real good answers.  The commonly provided explanations are not all that helpful, which are 503 errors are "generally" caused by:

- The backend server returned 503 due to a memory leak/issue in the code.
- Platform issue due to the backend server not running/ allocated
- Function host is down/restarting.

Anything the community has on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

**Update 2022-07-26:** It appears this issue is only with the Test + Code functionality in the Azure Portal.  While `503` is returned there, Log Analytics shows everything working as expected.  When the endpoint is hit from API Management or externally from Postman or similar a `200` response is returned with the expected result.

Comment: Consumption plan's default minimum timeout value is 5mins, and max timeout value is 10mins. what is done inside your original python function - any DB calls, or external API calls ? check all your dependencies are present, even if your function did not start fine or failed on any dependency, you would get a 5XX error. last resort, you can simply delete this function app and create a fresh one and see if that resolves...believe me it has happened for some.

Comment: One of your dependency package could be causing you this issue, check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/recover-python-functions?tabs=vscode#a-regression-from-third-party-packages) section

Comment: My actual function does make an API call to Azure Resource Manager and write records to Cosmos DB.  However, I don't think those are the problem given that the minimal example above deployed by itself to a Function App fails.  I updated the example to call out that my requirements.txt file is empty (although in my real function they are all already pinned).  I also clarified I have fully destroyed and redeployed all of these resources with different configs and in different regions with different sku.  Thanks for the feedback!